Curve integral $(\sin x-y^3, \cos y+x^3, xyz)$
I have some troubles with calculating the following curve integral
$u=(\sin x-y^3, \cos y+x^3, xyz)$ along the intersection between the plane $z=4$ and surface $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$.
My solution:
I'm using Stokes' theorem where I first calculate $rot(u)=(xz,-yz,3x^2+3y^2)$, then the following parametrization r=$(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ yields
$$
r_x' \times r_y' = \bigg( -\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, -\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, 1 \bigg)
$$
which I change orientation to
$$
\bigg( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, -1 \bigg).
$$
Since we are given from the problem that $z=4$ and $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$, we should have $x^2+y^2=z^2=4^2=16$. Thus, the surface should have a radius of 4, but the solution says 2 (why?)/
My calculations yields
$$
\iint u \cdot dr = \iint (\nabla \times u) \cdot N dS = \iint (xz,-yz,3x^2+3^2) \cdot \big( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, -1 \big) dxdy
$$
$$
= \iint \frac{x^2z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} - \frac{y^2z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} -3(x^2+y^2) dxdy
$$
plug in $z$
$$
=\iint -2x^2-4y^2 dxdy = -2 \iint x^2+2y^2 dxdy
$$
change to polar coordinates
$$
-2 \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^4 \big(r^2 \cos^2 \phi + 2r^2 \sin^2 \phi \big)rd \phi dr
$$
Why is this wrong, and what did I miss?
The soulution should equal(?)
$$
-3 \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^2 r^3 dr d \phi.
$$
Thanks for all insights.
Sincerely, TS

The curve you're integrating over is
$$
z=4\wedge x^2+y^2-z^2=0\implies x^2+y^2=4^2
$$
Its normal vector is actually $\boldsymbol{\hat n}=(0,0,1)$. You can compute it maybe using
$$\boldsymbol{\hat n}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol x}{\partial x}\times \dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol x}{\partial y}}{\left\lVert \dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol x}{\partial x}\times \dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol x}{\partial y} \right\rVert},\enspace\boldsymbol x=(x,y,z)$$
From $z=4$ we get all its partials are $0$. Therefore,
$$\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol x}{\partial x}\times \dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol x}{\partial y}=
\begin{vmatrix}
\boldsymbol i & \boldsymbol j & \boldsymbol k\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=\boldsymbol k\implies \boldsymbol{\hat n}=\boldsymbol k$$
Now we make use of Stokes' theorem:
$$\oint_{x^2+y^2=4} (\sin x-y^3,\cos y+x^3,xyz)\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol r=\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 4}(xz,-yz,3x^2+3y^2)\cdot(0,0,1)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$
The last integral may be easier to compute by employing polar coordinates:
$$3\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 4}(x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=3\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4r^3\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta$$
The differing in the sign might have to do with the original curve being integrated clockwise or counter-clockwise. As for the radius, theirs is incorrect or you got the problem formulation wrong.

I just realized the alternative OP was referring to. The other surface we can use to exploit Stokes' theorem is
$$\boldsymbol x=\left(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right),\enspace z\in[0,4].$$
Or rather in cylindrical coordinates,
$$\boldsymbol x=\left(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta,\rho\right), \enspace \rho\in[0,4],\enspace \theta\in[0,2\pi].$$
By the same method,
$$\boldsymbol{\hat n}\,\mathrm dS=\left(-\rho\cos\theta\,\boldsymbol i-\rho\sin\theta\,\boldsymbol j+\rho\,\boldsymbol k\right)\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta,$$
and thus, the contour integral now becomes
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4\rho^3(3-\cos(2\theta))\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta .$$
Since
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(2\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta=0,$$
we get the same result as before.

Thank you for input. The question is stated correct, but I forgot to mention that the curve is clockwise. So basically I didn't compute the normal vector correct, the parameterization should have been $r=(x,y,4)$ but why is this the case? Why can we not solve for z in terms of x and y here? Regarding the radius, the solution just says that the intersection with the plane $z=4$ is a circle with radius 2. Thanks.

I updated my answer. As for the radius trouble, I checked the value of the line integral and it coincides with the radius $4$ integral I obtained. Maybe the original problem was for $z=x^2+y^2$ instead?

It's stated correct, but maybe there is an error in the question. So when do we use $\mathbf{x}=(x,y,z)$ and $\mathbf{x}=(x,y,\phi(x,y))$?

As long as the surface is found inside the interior of the curve, both ways are correct. In case we intersect a plane with some other surface I'd prefer doing the first since the plane eases calculations.
